# HTTP get request Access Denied

Tags: python-3.x, url, web-scraping, http-get, access-denied

Trying to understand why I am getting access denied when attempting to download the index.html from [www.gamestop.com](http://www.gamestop.com). I have figured out how to get around it. https://www.gamestop.com/on/demandware.static/Sites-gamestop-us-Site/-/default/v1592871955944/js/main.js. I was wondering if anyone understood why the basic url ([www.gamestop.com](http://www.gamestop.com)) is rejected.

```
Code:
import requests
import http.client as http_client
import logging

headers = {
'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'cache-control':'max-age=0',
'connection':'keep-alive',
'dnt':'1',
'downlink':'10',
'ect':'4g',
'rtt':'50',
'sec-fetch-dest':'document',
'sec-fetch-mode':'navigate',
'sec-fetch-site':'none',
'sec-fetch-user':'?1',
'upgrade-insecure-requests':'1',
'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.410    3.97 Safari/537.36'
}

http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True
r = requests.get('https://www.gamestop.com', headers=headers)
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers)

Output:
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.gamestop.com:443
send: b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.gamestop.com\r\nuser-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.410    3.97 Safari/537.36\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\naccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nconnection: keep-alive\r\naccept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\ncache-control: max-age=0\r\ndnt: 1\r\ndownlink: 10\r\nect: 4g\r\nrtt: 50\r\nsec-fetch-dest: document\r\nsec-fetch-mode: navigate\r\nsec-fetch-site: none\r\nsec-fetch-user: ?1\r\nupgrade-insecure-requests: 1\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n'
header: Server: AkamaiGHost
header: Mime-Version: 1.0
header: Content-Type: text/html
header: Content-Length: 265
header: Expires: Fri, 26 Jun 2020 19:54:19 GMT
header: Date: Fri, 26 Jun 2020 19:54:19 GMT
header: Connection: close
header: Server-Timing: cdn-cache; desc=HIT
header: Server-Timing: cdn-cache; desc=HIT
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://www.gamestop.com:443 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 265
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;gamestop&#46;com&#47;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;19e8d93f&#46;1593201259&#46;5c2b9d0
</BODY>
</HTML>

403
{'Server': 'AkamaiGHost', 'Mime-Version': '1.0', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Length': '265', 'Expires': 'Fri, 26 Jun 2020 19:54:19 GMT', 'Date': 'Fri, 26 Jun 2020 19:54:19 GMT', 'Connection': 'close', 'Server-Timing': 'cdn-cache; desc=HIT, edge; dur=1'}
```

Comment: Many sites don't allow access from cross-domain hosts, as it's a security risk. Also to prevent scraping of their servers. Since you aren't identifying yourself as an accepted domain to the server, it rejects your request.

Comment: What do you mean an accepted domain? I have no problem accessing the site through a web browser, I am rejected through any means that is not a recognized web browser. curl / wget / python. Using the dev tools in the browser I was able to get the setup for curl / wget, and the headers but those get rejected.

Comment: The term domain may have been poor nomenclature on my part. "Origin" is probably the better term. That being said, removing the object oriented approach and just making a request with the headers you provided, I received a 200 response, and the page HTML. You are referring to "self.headers" in your sample Web_Scrapper class, but it's never assigned. Is this because this is quickly thrown together sample code? Or is this direct from your source implementation?

Comment: Could you post request.get you used?

Comment: `requests.get("http://www.gamestop.com/", headers=headers)` where `headers` is copy pasted from yours, but editing it to be in Python dictionary syntax (keys and values are strings).

Comment: This is what I attempted using the headers and a simple get requests. Is this the same as yours? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: As far as the actual request, yes it's the same. However, I get a successful response of the page. When I print the headers, I get a different server than you (Cloudflare vs AkamaiGhost). Also, your headers are showing as a cache hit, so I think you're just getting a cached failure returned. My request always comes back as a cache miss. I'm not sure if that information will help you at all, and at that point it's outside my expertise. The issue seems to be in the different access point handling of the request.

Comment: thank you, gives me something to work from.

Answer (score 1):

This is a code from my another project.
By using python fake user agent you can bypass this;
Use google to learn more about those module that i used here..

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
executable_path=r'C:\Users\ASHIK\Desktop\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.myntra.com/men?f=Categories%3ATshirts&p=1")
html_doc = driver.page_source
with open('myntra-ecom.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as hfile:
    hfile.writelines(html_doc)
    hfile.close()

print("Html file Downloaded...")
```